# Default Mongodb settings for mongodb connection in spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot and am trying to figure out how I can see a list of all the default properties for the MongoDB connection.

I looked at `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` but it's abstract and I can't see where the defaults come from. Looking at the class hierarchy for this class I can't see any default implementation in the Spring libs I have.

Where are the defaults for this connection? I don't see any properties files either, but might be missing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue not too long ago. The [official spring-data-mongodb documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-connectors) doesn't really mention any details about connection properties and their default values.

However, you can find more detailed information about the connection parameters in the [MongoDB Java Driver Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/connection/connection-options/#std-label-connection-options) and even more detailed [in the Connection string docs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.4/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.html) including some default values.

Spring Data MongoDB uses default values generated by calling the builder method for [MongoClientSettings](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/upcoming/fundamentals/connection/mongoclientsettings/).